# How to specify a callback method for IAsyncOperation

Tags: c++, asynchronous, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to specify a method to be called after finishing an `async` operation?

Platform : C++, Windows Phone 8

I need to implement non-blocking method for sending UDP packets asynchronously. And them have my method:

```
onWriteComplete(int errorCode)
```

called back when the operation completes.

Here's what I've tried:

```
res = await asyncWrite();
onWriteComplete( res );
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asynchronous operations work in similar ways across all languages in Windows Phone 8 and Windows RT applications. The asynchronous operation returns an IAsyncOperation result which you can use to chain a function to run when the operation completes.

In C++ you can create tasks and chain them in a way similar to C# using the [create_task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh913025.aspx) and [task::then](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750044.aspx) functions. Check [Asynchronous Programming in C++ (Windows Store Apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780559.aspx) for an example.

The sample creates a task from an IAsyncOperation result and schedules another task to execute when the first task completes:

```
auto deviceEnumTask = create_task(deviceOp);

// Call the task’s .then member function, and provide
// the lambda to be invoked when the async operation completes.
deviceEnumTask.then( [this] (DeviceInformationCollection^ devices ) 
{       
    for(int i = 0; i < devices->Size; i++)
    {
        DeviceInformation^ di = devices->GetAt(i);
        // Do something with di...          
    }       
}); // end lambda
```

Comment: Note that the DeviceInformationCollection^ should probably be task<DeviceInformationCollection^> and inside the lambda you use .get to retrieve the actual device information collection.  The call to .get will throw an exception if the deviceEnumTask failed (or threw an exception), thus allowing you to catch the failure.

Comment: For any curious reader not familiar with the `^` notation, like me, it is a language expension by Microsoft called [`C++/CX`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CX). Traditional C++ programming doesn't have such syntax.

Comment: @CodeDoggo this is a Windows Phone question. That's what all those doc examples used back then. As for `Traditional C++` .... which one? C++11, 14, 17 or 20? Especially when it comes to Unicode and specifically UTF8, where the only standard way to convert between `char` and `char8_t` was deprecated by C++20

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Traditional C++ as in without the carrot symbols everywhere. And this code doesn't just apply to Windows phones - it also applies to UWP applications as well. I had never seen C++/CX before and I thought I would call it out for any future readers - no harm, no foul.