# Toast Notification Listener in Native C++

Tags: c++, windows, notifications, toast

The scenario I encountered is: My app would listen to any popped-up toast notification and do user-defined staff. I Spent time on the msdn, and it looks like only windows 10 supports the toast notification listener staff, and only found an example has been provided by C#:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2016/05/26/notification-listener-documentation-windows-10/

Do they have an alternative C++ code for this?

Answer (score 1):

UserNotificationListener requires the very latest version of Windows 10, 10.0.14393.0, Windows 10 Anniversary Update, only released a couple months ago.

If you’re OK with that limitation, than yes, you can use it from C++.

The simplest way is set “Consume the Windows Runtime language Extensions (/ZW)” in your project properties. You can also set this compiler option for the individual .cpp source file where you going to use that UserNotificationListener class.

Note the documentation for [UserNotificationListener class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.management.usernotificationlistener) and its methods have “C++” tab.

Unfortunately, C++ currently has no “await”. To get results of asynchronous methods like RequestAccessAsync and others, you’ll have to write some .then() with lambdas. [See this answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15573272/126995).